Print to local USB printer when using VNC over a VPN
We have client computer C. There is a NAS running OpenVPN at a remote location. Network access has been enabled on the NAS/OpenVPN to allow clients to communicate with the rest of the network. A Remote computer R also at this remote location, and needs to be accessible via VNC.
We have succeeded in being able to connect to R from C using OpenVPN and establishing a VNC connection to the Remote Computer R.
It would be good though if Client C could click Print during the VNC session to the Remote computer R, and have the print sent to it's local printer (connected to the Client C with a USB cable). Similar to how RDP allows.
However, we want to avoid RDP.
Client C can access resources on Remote Computer R but not the other way around. C can ping R, but since the IP of C is a VPN assigned address 8.x.x.x we can't seem to get R to access the resources on C (such as being able to connect to a shared printer that is attached to C using a USB cable). This would solve our problem if we could make that work.
Is it possible to do this?
